# Java : Method return

Tags: java, methods

```
public class EulerProblem14 {

 int chainLength=1;
public int findChainLength(int number){
    System.out.println("number "+number);
    System.out.println("Chainlength  "+chainLength);

    if(number==1){
       System.out.println("the number is finally 1 return chain length");
       return chainLength;
    }
   if(number%2==0){
       chainLength++;
     return findChainLength(number/2);
   }
   else {
       chainLength++;
       findChainLength(number*3+1);
   }
   System.out.println("THIS SHOULD NOT BE EXECUTED");
   return -1;
}
public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.println(new EulerProblem14().findChainLength(13));

}
```

While solving Project Euler [Problem 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14), I came across a weird problem in method return in java I never faced before . In the above method when the number is finally 1 it should return the count of a chain . But this is the output for input 13 .

> number 13 Chainlength  1
>
> number 40 Chainlength  2
>
> number 20 Chainlength  3
>
> number 10 Chainlength  4
>
> number 5 Chainlength  5
>
> number 16 Chainlength  6
>
> number 8 Chainlength  7
>
> number 4 Chainlength  8
>
> number 2 Chainlength  9
>
> number 1 Chainlength  10
>
> the number is finally 1 return chain length
>
> THIS SHOULD NOT BE EXECUTED
>
> THIS SHOULD NOT BE EXECUTED
>
> -1

The problem is in the last part when the number becomes 1 instead of returning chainlength = 10 it somehow skips it and executes code which should never be executed and returns -1 . It runs fine for all powers of 2 like 1,2,4,8 but fails for others .

This is probably a stupid mistake on my part . Nonetheless it is a problem for me .

Comment: I think you're just missing a return for the second invocation you have of findChainLength (in the else block)

Comment: First rule of using recursion is don't use recursion.  Second rule of using recursion is don't use recursion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't looked in detail, but I suspect this:

```
else {
    chainLength++;
    findChainLength(number*3+1);
}
```

should actually be:

```
else {
    chainLength++;
    return findChainLength(number*3+1);
}
```

You should then be able to remove the last two lines of the method entirely, as they're unreachable.

Comment: You got it !! Is actually that.